# jQuery Out of Memory error for Ajax submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following code is generating an `out of memory` error. `mdjm_dcf.packages_field` is a select field. When I select an option both Safari and IE freeze for a period of time and within IE the console is returning `SCRIPT7: Out of memory`.

If I send an alert immediately after the on change event it works, but after clicking OK it freezes.

Appreciate any guidance...

```
$("#" + mdjm_dcf.packages_field).on('change', '', function()    {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: mdjm_dcf.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            package : $("#" + mdjm_dcf.packages_field).val(),
            addons_field : $("#" + mdjm_dcf.addons_field),
            addons_type : mdjm_dcf.addons_type,
            action : "mdjm_dcf_update_contact_form_addon_options"
        },
        beforeSend: function()  {
            $("#" + mdjm_dcf.addons_field).addClass( "mdjm-updating" );
            $("#" + mdjm_dcf.addons_field).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
                $("#" + mdjm_dcf.addons_field).empty();

                if( field_type == 'dropdown' )  {
                    $("#" + mdjm_dcf.addons_field).append(response.addons);
                } else  {
                    $("#" + mdjm_dcf.addons_field).html(response.addons);   
                }

                $("#" + mdjm_dcf.addons_field).fadeTo("slow", 1);

                $("#" + mdjm_dcf.addons_field).removeClass( "mdjm-updating" );
            } else  {
                alert(response.msg);
                $("#" + mdjm_dcf.addons_field).fadeTo("slow", 1);
                $("#" + mdjm_dcf.addons_field).removeClass( "mdjm-updating" );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: do you need to POST the entire jquery object  $("#" + mdjm_dcf.addons_field) or do you want to do something like  $("#" + mdjm_dcf.addons_field).text() or val()?

Comment: Agh!! I just need the name, not the object! Thank you!!